# ELB and SSLInsecureRenegotiation

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I currently have SSLInsecureRenegotiation set to off on my Apache 2.4 Amazon Linux server, but I am still failing over at SSLLabs (Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation    SUPPORTED).  Do you know how to enable this on the ELB?

Answer (score 0):

That's a function of the ELB Security Policy.  A new predefined policy `ELBSecurityPolicy-2014-10` contains the fix you're looking for, or you can define a custom policy.  With an HTTPS listener in ELB, your instance's SSL configuration isn't visible to the outside world, because there are two different SSL sessions happening with each connection -- the browser connection to ELB and the ELB connection to your instance.  Your server config only impacts the second one.  The ELB security policy defines the first one.

http://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/CVE-2014-3566-advisory/

Comment: Hi, while the new ELBSecurityPolicy did disable SSL3 (which I had previously done on my own), I am still getting Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation Supported   DoS DANGER (more info) from SSL Labs.  It looks like the ELB doesn't support shutting off Client-Initiated Renegotiation?

Comment: You're apparently correct.  I was thinking of renegotation in terms of CVE-2014-3566, not in general.